# error: cannot convert ‘char (*)[6]’ to ‘char**’

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c-strings, implicit-conversion, incompatibletypeerror

So my problem is the following, im trying to pass an array of strings and trying to find a specific one but for some reason the compiler is giving me this error and i dont get it because im clearly passing an array of strings into the function.

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int find_uid(char* users[],char* uid)
{
    for (int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(users[i],uid) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char users[32][6];

int main()
{
    char* user;
    user = new char[6];
    strcpy(user,"10014");
    strcpy(users[6],user);
    printf("Result %d",find_uid(users,"10014"))
}
```

Comment: note - I have removed the [c] tag as the presence of `new` indicates you are trying to write in C++ (albeit using a C-like coding style) ; these are two different languages

Comment: Why are you trying to walk on your hands when you can walk on your feet?  Use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: `10014` doesn't fit in a `char[5]`, you need space for the trailing `'\0'`

Comment: _"because im clearly passing an array of strings ..."_ No, you don't.

Comment: [Using std::vector and std::string](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/670c868b0721a175).

Comment: `char users[32][6];` is an array of 32 `char[6]` arrays.  The function is expecting (a pointer to) an array of `char*` pointers.  Not the same thing!

Comment: got it but even when i wrote users[][] it still gave the same thing i think

Answer (score 2):

For starters using `strcpy` in this code snippet

```
user = new char[5];
strcpy(user,"10014");
```

invokes undefined behavior because the dynamically allocated array does not have a space to store the terminating zero character of the string literal `"10014"`. You need to allocate an array at least of `6` elements

```
user = new char[6];
```

The two-dimensional array users declared like

```
char users[32][5];
```

used as a function argument is converted implicitly to a pointer to its first element of the type `char ( * )[5]`.

On the other hand, the corresponding function parameter has the type `char **`.
These pointer types are not compatible. So the compiler issues an error.

You need to declare the function at least like

```
int find_uid( char ( *users )[5],char* uid);
```

Or i is even better to declare the function like

```
bool find_uid( const char users[][5], size_t n, const char *uid );
```

Again the second dimension of the array should be increased

```
char users[32][6];
```

if you want to use the string literal `"10014"` in the array.